# Good free backup software that remembers the external drive no matter what letter windows assigns to it?

Tags: windows-10, backup

I'm using some truly great and free backup software called AOEMEI

It is so easy to use, really great except for its 1 fatal flaw.

It can't remember the drives you backed up to, only the drive letters.

This means that if you backup to flash drives or sd cards, you can't repeat the backup or add to it incrementally *if the drive letter has changed*

changing drive letters are a common occurence in Windows.

AEOMEI works fine and I will continue to use it for my main external hard drive (which is always on the same letter)

But for secondary backups to flash drives and such it is usually not working due to the drive letter problem.

I'm not interested in reserving entire letters for 1 specific device in Windows.

What I'd like to do is find some good free backup software that remembers drives not based on letter but based on their unique IDs. I know this is possible however I don't know how to figure out which backup software supports this. This kind of thing is not listed on their feature pages.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? thanks.

Comment: Software Recommendations... where questions go to die... :(

Comment: You stated that you are not interested in fixing the drive letter, what's the reason? If you have different backup flash drives, you could even assign them the same letter if necessary.

Comment: You know maybe I should do that. Figure out how to assign them all the same letter. Then mark the flash drives with permanent marker specific numbers so that I know which backup profile to use.

Comment: That's how I do it, using a dedicated drive letter for all backups. Just plug in the flash drive and fix the letter, then remove it and plug in the next drive... Of course a tool recognizing the drive would be a more solid solution.